# How to change only one column name in julia

Tags: dataframe, julia, rename

If I have a dataframe like:

```
test = DataFrame(A = [1,2,3] , B= [4,5,6])
```

and I want to change only the name of `A`, what can I do? I know that I can change the name of all columns together by `rename!` but I need to rename one by one. The reason is that I'm adding new columns by `hcat` in a loop and need to give them unique names each time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `Pair` syntax:

```
julia> test = DataFrame(A = [1,2,3] , B= [4,5,6])
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ A     │ B     │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 4     │
│ 2   │ 2     │ 5     │
│ 3   │ 3     │ 6     │

julia> rename!(test, :A => :newA)
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ newA  │ B     │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 4     │
│ 2   │ 2     │ 5     │
│ 3   │ 3     │ 6     │

julia> test
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ newA  │ B     │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 4     │
│ 2   │ 2     │ 5     │
│ 3   │ 3     │ 6     │
```

With strings it is the same:

```
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ A     │ B     │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 4     │
│ 2   │ 2     │ 5     │
│ 3   │ 3     │ 6     │

julia> rename!(test, "A" => "newA")
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ newA  │ B     │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 4     │
│ 2   │ 2     │ 5     │
│ 3   │ 3     │ 6     │

julia> test
3×2 DataFrame
│ Row │ newA  │ B     │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │
├─────┼───────┼───────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 4     │
│ 2   │ 2     │ 5     │
│ 3   │ 3     │ 6     │
```

Comment: Thank you, is there any way I can do this with strings instead of symbols?

Comment: Yes - it is exactly the same. I will update the answer.